# Can't play video in android when using pushmodelaasync method but it's working in PushAsync method

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, apk-expansion-files

I have a video files that I unzipped from apk expansion method for android, I can view and play this video using PushAsync method with custom renderer using VideoView, but when I try to do PushModelAsync for batter user experience then it showing black window, and also in the error I can see log that file not found, but nothing wrong with my code.

GetVideo function just return the Video filename

string uri = "";
                VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.videoView = new VideoView(Context);

```
                uri = (Path.Combine(documentsPath, GetVideo()));

            VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.mMediaPlayer.SetDataSource(Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri));
            VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.mMediaPlayer.Prepare();

            MainActivity.MainActivityInstance.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
            base.SetNativeControl(VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.videoView);


            SetCallBack();
            Control.Layout(0, 200, VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.mMediaPlayer.VideoHeight, VideoPlayer_CustomRenderer.mMediaPlayer.VideoWidth);
```

Comment: Getting null expectation in surface creation  async  public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            try
            {
                        mMediaPlayer.SetDisplay(holder);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            
        }

Comment: have you make a breakpoint to see which line it throws error?

Comment: void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder) { try { mMediaPlayer.SetDisplay(holder); } catch (Exception ex) { } }

Comment: could you show the complete code of the renderer and how you call  pushModeAsync method to open the video

Comment: PushModelAsync method call on a button click of a ContentPage of xamarin forms. i have already shown complete code of my renderer

Comment: could you share your test project on github,then we can test it and could find the issue aster